# How to make one to many relation in Mongoose by pushing array?

Tags: node.js, express, mongoose

I am having two collection i.e Project and developer.
I want to assign multiple project to a developer.
I am able to assign single project to  developer but how can i assign multiple? its quite confusing for me.

I think pushing array will be good but how to do is?
Thanks in advance.

controller for assigning project to developer

```
/*@Submit project to developer */
exports.putDevAssign = (req, res, next) => {
    const {projectId, teamId} = req.body

    Team.findByIdAndUpdate(teamId, { project : projectId }, { new: true }).populate('project')
    .then(result => {
        const member = result
        res.render('team/project-list', {
            result,
            member
        })
    })
    .catch(err => console.log(err))
}
```

developer model

```
const mongoose = require('mongoose')
const bcrypt = require('bcryptjs')

const Schema = mongoose.Schema

const teamSchema = new Schema({
    position: {
        type: String,
        required: true
    },
    project: {
        type: Schema.Types.ObjectId,
        ref:'Admin'
    },
    email: {
        type: String,
        required: true
    },
    password: {
        type: String,
        required:true
    }
})

teamSchema.pre('save', function(next) {
    const team = this

    bcrypt.hash(team.password, 10, function (error, encrypted) {
        team.password = encrypted
        next()
    })
}) //hook

module.exports = mongoose.model('Team', teamSchema)
```

and Project Schema

```
const mongoose = require('mongoose')

const Schema = mongoose.Schema

const adminSchema = new Schema({
    pName: {
        type: String,
        required: true
    },
    category: {
        type: String,
        required: true
    },
    totalPrice: {
        type: Number,
        required: true
    },
    advance: {
        type: Number,
        required: true
    },
    logo: {
        type: String,
    },
    startDate: {
        type: String,
        required: true
    },
    endDate: {
        type: String,
        required: true
    },
    cName: {
        type: String,
        required: true
    },
    address: {
        type: String,
        required: true
    },
    email: {
        type: String,
        required: true
    },
    number: {
        type: Number,
        required: true
    },
    logo: {
        type: String,
        required: true
    },
    info :{
        type: String
    },
    /* ,
    docs: {
        type: Array
    } */


}, {
    timestamps:true
})

module.exports = mongoose.model('Admin',adminSchema)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After surfing and taking help from Internet i fixed this. This can be done

1. Adding bracket to Schema

```
const mongoose = require('mongoose')
const bcrypt = require('bcryptjs')

const Schema = mongoose.Schema

const teamSchema = new Schema({
    position: {
        type: String,
        required: true
    },
    project: [{
        type: Schema.Types.ObjectId,
        ref:'project'
    }],
    email: {
        type: String,
        required: true
    },
    password: {
        type: String,
        required:true
    }
})

teamSchema.pre('save', function(next) {
    const team = this

    bcrypt.hash(team.password, 10, function (error, encrypted) {
        team.password = encrypted
        next()
    })
}) //hook

module.exports = mongoose.model('Team', teamSchema)
```

2. Then using $push functionality and checking for the unique project assigned to developer codes looks like this

```
/*@Submit assign project to developer */
exports.putDevAssign = (req, res, next) => {
    const {projectId, teamId} = req.body

    Team.findById(teamId)
    .then(result => {
        if(result.project.length == 0 ) {
            Team.findByIdAndUpdate(teamId, {$push: { project : projectId } }, { new: true }).populate('project')
                    .then(result => {
                        res.redirect('/Assigned-Developer/' + teamId)
                    })
                    .catch(err => console.log(err))
        } else {
            for(let i = 0; i < result.project.length; i++) {
                if( projectId == result.project[i] ) {  
                    req.flash('message', 'Already Assigned')
                    return res.redirect('/Assigned-Developer/' + teamId)  // project already in list
                }
            }
            // if code reached here, project not in current project list, must add it
            Team.findByIdAndUpdate(teamId, {$push: { project : projectId } }, { new: true }).populate('project')
            .then(result => {
                return res.redirect('/Assigned-Developer/' + teamId)
            })
            .catch(err => console.log(err))
            }
        })
    .catch(err => console.log)
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Firstly your project in your team schema needs to be in an Array like this :

```
const mongoose = require('mongoose')
const bcrypt = require('bcryptjs')

const Schema = mongoose.Schema

const teamSchema = new Schema({
    position: {
        type: String,
        required: true
    },
    project: [{
        type: Schema.Types.ObjectId,
        ref:'project'
    }],
    email: {
        type: String,
        required: true
    },
    password: {
        type: String,
        required:true
    }
})

teamSchema.pre('save', function(next) {
    const team = this

    bcrypt.hash(team.password, 10, function (error, encrypted) {
        team.password = encrypted
        next()
    })
}) //hook

module.exports = mongoose.model('Team', teamSchema)
```

Then you create another schema named Projects Hema where you store the projects like this :

```
const mongoose = require('mongoose')
const bcrypt = require('bcryptjs')

const Schema = mongoose.Schema

const projectSchema = new Schema({
    title: {
        type: String,
        required: true
    },
      description: {
        type: String,
        required: true
    }

})


module.exports = mongoose.model('Project', projectSchema)
```

Finally in your codes

```
exports.putDevAssign = (req, res, next) => {
    const {projectId, teamId} = req.body

    Team.findByIdAndUpdate(teamId, { project : projectId }, { new: true }).populate('project')
    .then(result => {
        res.render('team/project-list', {
            result,
            member
        })
    })
    .catch(err => console.log(err))
}
```

Comment: by the way i have Schema for project. check it i have updated!

Comment: After creating array in schema how to push multiple data to it?